# Changing some of static content of shared partial view depending on main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have several shared razor partial views in my application to show some details of products on different pages. Now i need to change some of links inside partial views depending on what main view rendered that partial.

For example:

If partial view is rendered inside "index.cshtml", one of the links in partial view should be:

```
<a href="www.site1.com">site1 called from index.cshtml</a>
```

and if it's inside "insert.cshtml" then link need to be

```
<a href="www.someothersite2.com">other site that's not 1 and it's called from insert.cshtml</a>
```

something like:

```
@if (something.parentview = "index.cshtml")
{  <a href="www.site1.com">site1 called from index.cshtml</a>}
else {

    <a href="www.someothersite2.com">other site that's not 1 and it's called from insert.cshtml</a>
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use `ViewBag`. Set the values in each of your controllers and use them in the partial view.

Comment: This was bad example, i changed it now... My problem don't have anything with controllers, i just need to show different data in one or two lines, depending from where is shared partial rendered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the Shared PartialView you know where are you.
Is far more easy to pass a parameter to your partial at the time of rendering that rely in "detect" inside of which view is rendered. Imagine... you have 3 levels of nesting... things get more complicated. Imagine if you change routing or view names?

You can use the ViewBag to pass the parameter: in your view you can set something to check inside the Partial. Not controller code is needed.

A more robust approach is pass a ViewModel to your Partial, but if the only data you need to pass is just a parameter, the ViewBag is simpler.